# How can we prove that the running time bound of an algorithm is tight?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, big-o

Suppose we can prove that an algorithm, invoked with an input of size `n`, runs in time `O(f(n))`.

I want to prove that this running time bound is tight. Two questions:

1. Wouldn't it suffice to give a special input and show that the running time is at least `f(n)`?
2. I've read that one possibility for proving the tightness is to "reduce sorting to it". I've no idea what is meant by that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Wouldn't it suffice to give a special input and show that the running
>   time is at least f(n)?

**Yes, assuming you are talking about the *worst case complexity***.

If you are talking about worst case complexity - and you have proved it is running in `O(f(n))`, if you find an input that "worse" than `C*f(n))` for some constant `C` - you effectively proved that the algorithm (under worst case performance) is in `Ω(f(n))`, and since `O(f(n)) [intersection] Ω(f(n)) = Theta(f(n))`, it means your algorithm is running in `Theta(f(n))` under worst case analysis. 

**Note** that it should actually be a "family" of examples, since if I claim "yes, but this is correct only for small `n` values, and not for `n>N` (for some `N`), you can show me that this family of examples also covers the case where `n>N`, and still be valid.

Symmetrically, if you proved an algorithm has best case performance of `Ω(f(n))`, and you found some input that runs "better" (faster) than `C*f(n))` for some constant `C`, you effectively proved the algorithm is `Theta(f(n))` under best case analysis.

This trick does NOT work for average case analysis - where you should calculate the expectancy of the run time, and a singular example is not helpful.

> I've read that one possibility for proving the tightness is to "reduce
>   sorting to it". I've no idea what is meant by that

This is done to prove a much stronger claim, that **there is no algorithm (at all) that can solve some problem at the desired time**.

The common usage of it is to assume there is some black box algorithm `A` that runs in some `o(g(n))` time, and then use `A` to build a sorting algorithm that runs in `o(nlogn)` time. However, since sorting is `Ω(nlogn)` problem, we have a contradiction, and we can conclude out assumptions about `A` are wrong, and it cannot run in the desired time.

This helps us to prove a stronger claim: Not only OUR algorithm has this lower bound, but ALL algorithms that solve the specific problem has this lower bound.

Comment: So, I need to show that the problem, that my algorithm solves, is equivalent to the problem of sorting data, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Not exactly, you can show that you can solve sorting with it in o(nlogn) time.

Answer (score 1):

ad 1.: Yes, but you must be able to find such input of size n for any n. An example of size 3 that is processed in 9 steps doesn't really prove anything.

ad 2.: If you can modify a sequence of elements so that your algorithm effectively sorts it (you get a sorted sequence after some processing of the output), you've reduced sorting to it. And because sorting (by comparison) cannot be faster than O(n log(n)), this can be used to prove that your algorithm cannot be faster than O(n log(n)).

Of course, the input and output processing functions cannot be slower than or equal to O(n log(n)) for this argument to be valid, otherwise you could sort the array and prove that an O(1) algorithm that just returns the input array is in fact at least O(n log(n)) :).

Comment: About 1: not necessary for any `n`. It is sufficient to show that there is such an input for all sufficiently large `n`.